# How to load cardview GridView with Animations in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, cardview

I have created android app like gallery which have some images using gridview fragment.

Functionality of my application is working fine and image showing in fragment gridview and also my second activity open when i click on item but i want to show cardview GridView with Animations.

Also if it is easier default image in place of loading images instead of progress bar will be fine.

Here is my application fragment code :

```
public class CallFragment extends Fragment {

    GridView grid;
        String[] plan = {
                "Student Bundle",
                "SMS Plus Bundle",
                "Instagram",
                "Facebook",
                "Flickr"

        } ;
        String[] web = {
                "*3000",
                "*106*1",
                "Instagram",
                "Facebook",
                "Flickr"

        } ;
        int[] imageId = {
                R.drawable.calla,
                R.drawable.smsb,
                R.drawable.person7,
                R.drawable.person7,
                R.drawable.person7

        };
        int[] fullimg = {
                R.drawable.callaa,
                R.drawable.smsbb,
                R.drawable.person7,
                R.drawable.person7,
                R.drawable.person7

        };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call,container,false);

            CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), plan, web, imageId, fullimg);

            grid=(GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    String value=(String)grid.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Book.class);
                    intent.putExtra("web", web[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("plan", plan[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("imageId", imageId[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("fullimg", fullimg[i]);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            return view;
        }
```

Here is my application CustomAdapter code :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> personNames;
    ArrayList<String> personCode;
    ArrayList<Integer> personImages;
    ArrayList<Integer> personImages1;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> personNames, ArrayList<String> personCode, ArrayList<Integer> personImages, ArrayList<Integer> personImages1) {
        this.context = context;
        this.personCode = personCode;
        this.personNames = personNames;
        this.personImages = personImages;
        this.personImages1 = personImages1;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // infalte the item Layout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v); // pass the view to View Holder
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // set the data in items
        //holder.name.setText(personNames.get(position));
        holder.image.setImageResource(personImages.get(position));
        //holder.image.setImageResource(personImages1.get(position));
        // implement setOnClickListener event on item view.
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // open another activity on item click
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("image", personImages.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                intent.putExtra("name", personNames.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                intent.putExtra("code", personCode.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                intent.putExtra("image", personImages1.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                context.startActivity(intent); // start Intent
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personNames.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // init the item view's
        TextView name;
        TextView code;
        ImageView image;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // get the reference of item view's
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            code = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is example of my requirement :

[image]

My gridview looks like this :

[image: My gridview looks like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an separate XML file under anim and apply in the onBindViewHolder.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {


        // Here you apply the animation when the view is bound
        setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
    }

    /**
     * Here is the key method to apply the animation
     */
    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
    {.             int lastPosition=0;

        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition)
        {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can i use look like this : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>

Comment: can you tell me xml name which you use in your code

Comment: slide_in_left name for xml

Comment: If this was helpful please check this as the answer. I will be useful for others

Comment: Created an separate XML name : animation_style and your code add in my CustomAdapter then showing error Cannot resolve symbol 'lastposition'

Comment: Sorry my mistake, make it int lastPosition=0;

Comment: you mean change name of XML file?

Comment: please check again and tell me where i add your code in my CustomAdapter because its still showing same error of Cannot resolve symbol 'lastposition'

Comment: i have created xml file name slide_in_left using this code : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>

Comment: public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private Context context;
    // Allows to remember the last item shown on screen
    private int lastPosition = -1;.                                    Define lastPosition at the start.

Comment: Thanks its working from left to right so can you tell me how can change bottom to top

Comment: Google for top to bottom an change the XML code. Check this as your answer in the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help i have set it as i want

Answer (score 0):

You can apply animations on RecyclerView  using [this](https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213) tutorial.

and for default image just put a src property inside your imageview in **R.layout.rowlayout** XML file

Answer (score 0):

Used this Recyclerview with Load animation

[Recyclerview Load Animation](https://github.com/sharish/ShimmerRecyclerView)